# If statement code

Tags: android, eclipse

OK I am trying to make a app which will only accept 1 word of any text.I am use the edittext to let the user put in the text and button for them to give them a toast with the words your incorrect or correct

The problem is when i use the if statement i cant get it to work can some one please identify the problem here is my code

```
public class IfActivity extends Activity {
Button GO;
EditText TEXT;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GO = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
    TEXT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Textin);

    GO.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if ("hello".equals(TEXT)) {
                Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(IfActivity.this,
                        "PASSWORD IS CORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                andEggs.show();
            } else {
                Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(IfActivity.this,
                        "PASSWORD IS INCORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                andEggs.show();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: What does *"i cant get it to work"* mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {             
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
 String tempTxt = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Textin)).getText().toString();
 if ("hello".equals(tempTxt )) {
     Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(IfActivity.this,"PASSWORD IS CORRECT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     andEggs.show();
  } 
 else{
   Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(IfActivity.this,"PASSWORD IS INCORRECT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   andEggs.show();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

`TEXT` is not a String. It is a reference variable of EditText.

```
if (TEXT.getText().toString().equals("hello"))
{

}
```

Comment: thanks dude I knew there was something I was missing just couldnt lay a finger on it spot on thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
if("hello".equals((findViewById(R.id.Textin)).getText().toString())) {  // show toast}
```